# Compare-Object not working if I don't list the properties

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have 2 Excel spreadsheets I am trying to compare:

```
$OleDbAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter “Select * from [Report$]“,”Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\FIS-BIC Reporting\Report Output Files\Product-Marketing\TEST_XI\ECM - Pipeline by LOB_04182013_040544.xls;Extended Properties=”"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES”";”
$RowsReturned = $OleDbAdapter.Fill($DataTable)

$OleDbAdapter2 = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter “Select * from [Report$]“,”Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\FIS-BIC Reporting\Report Output Files\Product-Marketing\ECM - Pipeline by LOB_04182013_074004.xls;Extended Properties=”"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES”";”
$RowsReturned2 = $OleDbAdapter2.Fill($DataTable2)

Compare-Object $DataTable $DataTable2
```

It returns nothing. I know that in the 6th column, they are different. If I specify "-property F6", it does return the difference.  Any idea why it doesn't unless I specify the property? The number of columns can vary (though will be the same for each of the files in the comparison), so specifying the properties specifically won't work.

Answer (score 31):

If you don't specify the **-Property** parameter, **Compare-Object** doesn't compare all properties, it compares the results of invoking the **.ToString()** method on both objects. So, `Compare-Object $DataTable $DataTable2` compares **$DataTable1.ToString()** with **$DataTable1.ToString()**. The **.ToString()** method returns an empty string when invoked on a DataTable object, so there is no difference to report.

For example:

```
$file1 = Get-Item somefilename
$file1 = Get-Item anotherfilename
Compare-Object $file1 $file2
```

This will return the difference between the full paths of the two files, like this:

```
InputObject              SideIndicator
-----------              -------------
<path>\anotherfilename   =>
<path>\somefilename      <=
```

That's because invoking **.ToString()** on a FileInfo object returns its **FullName** property, so you're comparing the files' full path names.

Although the **-Property** parameter accepts multiple properties, listing all the properties is not the solution. Aside from being very tedious, it will not give you the results you want. If you list multiple properties, **Compare-Object** compares the *combination* of all the properties, and if any one of the listed properties is different, it returns a result showing all the listed properties (both ones that are the same and ones that are different) as a single difference.

What you need to do is iterate over a list of properties, and invoke **Compare-Object** once for each property:

```
$properties = ($DataTable | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
foreach ($property in $properties) {
  Compare-Object $DataTable $DataTable2 -Property "$property" | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

- In most cases, when comparing all properties of two objects, you'd want to use `Get-Member -MemberType Properties`, in order to get cover all property types. However, if you're comparing DataTable objects, you're better off using `Get-Member -MemberType Property` so that you're comparing only the properties corresponding to data fields, not other properties of the DataTable objects that have nothing to do with the data.
- This is written assuming that the number of columns is the same, as you stated, or at least that the number of columns in **$DataTable2** doesn't exceed the number of columns in **$DataTable**.

  If you can't reliably assume that, derive the **$properties** array from whichever one has more columns, by comparing `($DataTable | Get-Member -MemberType Property).Count` with `($DataTable2 | Get-Member -MemberType Property).Count` and using the properties from whichever is greater.
- Using **Format-Table** is important, it's not just there to make things look pretty. If you list multiple objects of the same type (in this case, arrays), PowerShell remembers the format of the first object, and uses it for all subsequent objects, unless you explicitly specify a format. Since the name of the first column will be different for each property (i.e., each column from the spreadsheet), the first column will be empty for all but the first difference encountered.

  The `-AutoSize` switch is optional. That *is* there just to make things look pretty. But you must pipe the results to a formatting filter. You can also use **Format-List** if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I didn't know it didn't compare all properties. I am havign a problem though. I really want to do a row by row compare.  To do that, I am thinking I need to add a key called something like RowNum to each and specify that as the key.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to compare entire rows, and return results if *any* of the columns in the compared rows contain different data? If so, see the part in the middle where I wrote "Although the -Property parameter accepts multiple properties, listing all the properties...will not give you the results you want." If you want to compare entire rows, listing all the properties (i.e., column names) in the -Property parameter *will* give the results you want. Is that the idea?

Comment: Correct - entire rows. It would be nice to know what column had the difference, but not essential. Is there a way to do that though without listing each property? Each spreadsheet can have a different number of columns.  I am planning on doing a bulk compare of 1000s of spreadsheets (they are sets, so only comparing spreadsheet a to b, c to d, etc). A and B have the same # of columns, but c and d will be different.

Comment: You could read all the property names of **$DataTable1** into an array and use that as the **-Property** argument. I'd need to know more about the structure of these DataTables in order to be more specific about how. I don't have an OLEDB driver for Excel installed, so I can't reproduce this locally. What are the property names like? You say that you can use **F6** as a property name, but that doesn't make sense to me. Wouldn't the property names be the same as the Excel column names, i.e. A, B, C, D, etc? How can the row # be part of the property names if all rows have the same properties?

Answer (score 8):

[Adi Inbar's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346380/45375) contains good background information about how `Compare-Object` works.

However, **there *is* a way to use `-Property` generically to compare *all* column values** - assuming that both input tables have the same column structure, or that the the tables should only be compared by the *first* table's columns:

```
# The original collection.
$coll1 = [pscustomobject] @{ one = '1a'; two = '2a'; three = '3a' },
         [pscustomobject] @{ one = "1b"; two = "2b"; three = '3b' }

# The other collection to compare the original to.
# Note the difference in the 2nd object in column 'two'
$coll2 = [pscustomobject] @{ one = '1a'; two = '2a'; three = '3a' },
         [pscustomobject] @{ one = "1b"; two = "2b!"; three = '3b' }

# PSv3+: Get the array of all property names to compare 
#        from the original collection.
# Note: 
#      * The assumption is that both collections have the same set of 
#        properties (or that the collections should only be compared by
#        the *first* collection's properties).
#      * In PSv2-, use the following instead:
#         $propsToCompare = $coll1[0].psobject.properties | % { $_.name }
$propsToCompare = $coll1[0].psobject.properties.name

# Compare the 2 collections by all property values.
# -PassThru means that any input object in which a difference is found
# is passed through as-is.
Compare-Object $coll1 $coll2 -Property $propsToCompare -PassThru
```

The above yields:

```
one two three SideIndicator
--- --- ----- -------------
1b  2b! 3b    =>           
1b  2b  3b    <=
```

Note how `=>` tells you that the selected object is exclusive to the *right* side and vice versa for `<=`

A caveat is that **`Compare-Object` is *slow*, because it cannot make assumptions about input data being *sorted*** and therefore has to read and compare both input collections *in full*.

**With *sorted* input, you can use `-SyncWindow <Int32>`** to speed things up, but that requires advance knowledge of how many items *at most* can differ between the two input collections following each difference found, and if the `-SyncWindow` value is too small, spurious differences will be reported.

---

**If you compare objects *as a whole* (no `-Property` argument), PowerShell uses the following comparison method**:

Note:

- Below, *LHS* refers to an object from the *reference* collection (`-ReferenceObject`) and *RHS* to an object from the *difference* collection (`-DifferenceObject`)
- The short of it is: **Unless the types involved implement `IComparable`** (which is true for strings and all primitive .NET types (the CLR's number types and `[char]`)) or have **custom `.ToString()` implementations with instance-specific return values** from which equality can be inferred, **whole-object comparison will *not* be meaningful**, and **objects will be treated as equal even when they aren't**.

The following logic is implemented in the [`TryCompare()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/16ec1cc32f9e60c9d76b074c865c32a5d2acf5a2/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L883) *engine* method, which is used whenever two values must be compared, irrespective of context.

- If the LHS is a *string*, string comparison is performed, which is case-*insensitive* and culture-*invariant* by default; the `-CaseSensitive` and `-Culture` parameters allow you to change that.
- If both the LHS and the RHS are *numbers* of (potentially different) .NET primitive types, numeric comparison is performed.
- Otherwise, an attempt is made to convert the RHS is to the type of the LHS and, if the type supports [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable), its `.CompareTo()` method is called to determine equality.
- Otherwise, the LHS and RHS are compared via the [`Object.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.Equals) method that all objects inherit or implement or, if the type implements interface `IEquatable<T>`, [`IEquatable<T>.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals).

  - If `System.Object.Equals()` is called, and a given type doesn't override it, only value types (`struct`s) composed only of other value-type instances will compare meaningfully; for reference types, only two references to the very same object instance are considered equal.
  - **Caveat**: As of PowerShell Core 7.1.0-preview.2, only if the `.Equals()` call returns `true` is the result used. The reason is that the comparison code is also used for *ordering* (sorting) values, where determining equality alone is not enough. In the context of `Compare-Object`, *not* using a `false` result is actually *inappropriate* for types that implement `IEquatable<T>` (and don't also implement `IComparable`) - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12498).

The remaining logic comes from [`ObjectCommandComparer.Compare()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/16ec1cc32f9e60c9d76b074c865c32a5d2acf5a2/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/ObjectCommandComparer.cs#L222) (which is also used by `Get-Unique` and `Select-Object -Unique`):

- If none of the above methods apply, the objects are compared by their `.ToString()` representations (with the same string-comparison specifics described above).

  - Note that for many types these will *not* result in meaningful comparison, because the default `.ToString()` implementation simply returns the *full type name* (e.g., `'System.IO.FileInfo'`), so that *all instances* of that type compare *the same*.