# Compare-Object - Trouble understanding Pipeing

Tags: powershell, pipe

I don't know what's going on with Compare-Object in my Script.

My Compare-Object outputs a perfect output

```
InputObject                                                                SideIndicator                                                             
-----------                                                                -------------                                                             
@{ComputerName=USSFMW-V03021; CollectionName=}                             ==                                                                        
@{ComputerName=USSFMW-V03013; CollectionName=}                             ==
```

Exporting this into an CSV works perfectly

```
Compare-Object  $alreadyCombs $Computers -IncludeEqual #| Export-CSV $newComptuersCSV
```

But this :

```
$test = Compare-Object  $alreadyCombs $Computers -IncludeEqual
```

results in an empty output:

```
{@{InputObject=; SideIndicator===}, @{InputObject=; SideIndicator===},
```

I'm not that long into powershell, and I wonder if I did not understand the logic behind Pipeing and putting the values into a variable.

At the moment, I'm exporting it into CSV, importing it again, deleting CSV... It works good but I can't show this code anybody, that's a pity ....^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259861/compare-object-not-working-if-i-dont-list-the-properties) ...perhaps a similar issue?  Your issue can be resolved by piping the compare-object cmdlet to select-object and selecting InputObject and SideIndicator.