# Sorting and Comparing Arraylists

Tags: powershell, sorting, arraylist, compare

I'm pretty new to Powershell and have a problem. 
It seems I can get neither the `Compare-Object` nor the `Sort-Object` funtions to work. 
I got two Arraylists which I fill with 10 objects of type "Table".

```
#Create Arraylists
$list1 = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$list2 = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList


#Declare Table-Class
class Table {
    [String] $name
    [Int] $number
}


#Fill list1
[Int] $i = 0
while ($i -lt 10) {
    $entry = new-Object Table
    $entry.name = "Name";
    $entry.number = $i;
    $list1.Add($entry)
    $i++
}

#Fill list2
[Int] $j = 10
while ($j -gt 0) {
    $entry = new-Object Table
    $entry.name = "name";
    $entry.number = $j;
    $list2.Add($entry)
    $j--
}
```

Now I want to compare these two ArrayLists like this:

`Compare-Object $list1 $list2 | ForEach-Object {$_.InputObject}`

This doesn't seem to work and I think it's because I'm not really doing anything with the comparison. If someone could help me with the correct Syntax I'd be really happy.
Anyway, I think this comparison would somehow return a `$false` boolean.
If that were true, I'd like to sort `$list2` by `$entry.number`.

I'm attempting this like that:

```
$list2 = $list2 | Sort-Object -Property { $_[1] }
```

But my list doesn't change at all. I already tried several different "solutions" but it seems none of these is a real "solution".

I'd be really glad if someone could help me or at least point me in the right direction.

---

EDIT: For future readers, here is the working syntax:

```
#sort list by the property number
$list2 = $list2 | sort-object -Property number

#count differences and if differences greater than 0, do stuff
[Int] $diff
$properties = $list1 | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($property in $properties) {
    $diff = 0
    $diff = (Compare-Object $list1 $list2 -Property "$property").count
    if ($diff -ne 0) {
        #do stuff
    }
    else {
        #do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by reading ***Get-Help Compare-Object*** and ***Get-Help Sort-Object***. I'm not sure that they do exactly what you think they do.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sorting does not work because `-Property` expects you to pass the name of an actual property. In your case the class two properties: `$name` and `$number`. You can also check what properties an object has by using `$list2 | Get-Member`. So in order to sort, you can use:

```
$list2 = $list2 | Sort-Object -Property number
```

Now the reason `Compare-Object` is not working is because it's implemented differently that one might expect. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346380/1244910) explaining how it works.

One other thing you should keep in mind: Calling `$list2.Add($entry)` actually returns an integer (the index of the inserted element). PowerShell returns all uncaptured output. This can cause some unexpected behavior/output if you are not careful. So you should get in the habit of writing `[void] $list2.Add($entry)`, unless you really want to return those indexes.

Comment: And another question, is it possible to get a boolean from the comparison? So I can save that in a variable and then execute some code depending if they are the same or different. Thanks so much, very helpful!

Comment: @Obongo I think `Compare-Object` returns nothing if it's equal. So a simple `$isEqual = ( Compare-Object .. ) -eq $null` should do the trick.