# Compare 2 CSV files line by line and print new lines only

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare 2 CSV files i.e. Old.csv and new.csv. I want to compare and  print only those lines which are not in old.csv as compared to the new.csv.

I want to print only new files which are not there in old file.

```
$a = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\old.csv 
$b = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\new.csv

$Green = $b | Where {$a -notcontains $_} $green
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question and don't post code in comments. Thank you

Comment: They are actually different objects, so it's not comparing if they hold the same values, it's comparing if they are the same things in memory, and they aren't. You will need to use `Compare-Object` and compare all their properties, to do what you want, as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270537/478656 - or use `Get-Content` to do it the way you are doing it and compare them "line of text by line of text". `compare-object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -Property $a[0].psobject.properties.name`

Answer (score 3):

Given that you want to find the new lines between two .csv files, you can use `Compare-Object`.

```
$a = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\old.csv 
$b = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\new.csv

Compare-Object  -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject | Export-Csv C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\difference.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Explanation of the Command:**

`Compare-Object  -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b` - Find the Difference between to Objects

`Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject` - Show only the different Objects and not the Indicator of `Compare-Object`

`Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation` - Stores the piped values into a .csv file without Type-Header.

---

If you only want to store the difference in a variable just delete the `Export-Csv` part:

```
$green = Compare-Object  -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

Comment: You'da best Sir :) Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

If you just interested in "*only those **lines** which are not in old.csv as compared to the new.csv*" and not in objects and as objects imported from `.csv` files contain only string type properties anyways.
Your suggestion in your question might actually work for you, but you will need to get the content as *lines* (using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6)) and not as *objects* (using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6))

```
$a = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\old.csv
$b = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\subhatnagar\Desktop\new.csv

$green = $b | Where {$a -notContains $_}
$green
```

> Beware that this solution compares the **lines** and not the **objects**,
>   this means that if e.g. swap a column, *all* the lines in the `new.csv` file
>   are considered different which would not be the case if you handle the input as
>   objects.